# composer require laravel/ui. Don't install illuminate/console v7.12.0

Tags: laravel, windows, laravel-6

I am working on bagiato(laravel). When I run the command "composer require laravel/ui" this error comes.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.    
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/console v7.12.0
    - don't install illuminate/console 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.15
    - don't install illuminate/console 7.x-dev|remove laravel/framework v6.18.15
    - don't install illuminate/console 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.15
    - Installation request for illuminate/console ^7.12 -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[7.x-dev, v7.12.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.15, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.15].
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install the wrong version of laravel/ui.

laravel/ui version 1 is what you want.  Version 2 is trying to install and only laravel 7+ supports it.

composer require vendor/package:version

composer require laravel/ui:1.2.0 <- latest version of laravel/ui that works with Laravel 6

Comment: Would appreciate you selecting this as the answer if this worked for you.